# HTML href to a div on the same page in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a list in HTML as below

```
<ul id="mymenu">
</ul>
```

And in the same HTML page there is a div tag like below

```
<div title="Settings" id="mysetting" class="panel">
..........
</div>
```

In my javascript I am appending to the list as below using jQuery.

```
$("#mymenu").append("<li><a class='class1 class2' href='#mysetting' id='my id'>" + "Click me" + "</a></li>");
```

When I am on Android 3.0 and above this does what I want and take me to the div I want when I click the list item. But in Android 2.3 this is not working. Can someone here please tell me why. Is there any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or please tell me if there is any other way that can work.

Comment: Well for one thing, `my id` is not a valid ID. For another, rather than straight HTML, why not take advantage of what jQuery has to offer and establish using jQuery methods so you can have "full control" and make other amendments as needed, such as adding events, being able to visualize properties without reading long HTML and more. Something like: `$('<li />').append($('<a />', { class: 'class1 class2', href: '#mysetting', id: 'myID', text: 'Click me' })).appendTo('#mymenu');`

Comment: FYI, the rewrite is just a suggestion, not a necessity as the result would be the same. Everyone codes different!

Comment: @SpYk3HH I will have that tip thank you for that... :-) I cant understand why my code works on Android 3.0 and up and not on 2.3. Why this happens or any other way of doing that is very appreciated.